# How can I get VS Code to give a heads up when deleting a file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentally deleted a whole project without commiting but the thing is that VS Code doesn't give me a confirmation prompt when deleting a file/folder.

Is there a way to get a heads up when I'm about to delete something? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the setting `"explorer.confirmDelete": true,`, this will prompt a confirmation screen.

Another setting that helps my sanity in this situation.

`"files.enableTrash": true,` will move files to the OS trash instead of permanently deleting. This way you can go digging through the trash when this happens.

There is also

`"workbench.editor.closeOnFileDelete": false` which will keep open files that were deleted in the editor. A nice secondary option when deleting something.

Answer (score 1):

> "`workbench.editor.closeOnFileDelete`": false which will keep open files that were deleted in the editor. A nice secondary option when deleting something.

Make sure to use VSCode 1.75+ (Jan. 2023): [issue 126144](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/126144) ("Do not close tabs when a file is deleted when tab is not loaded") has been fixed with [commit 0a11eb](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/0a11eb426191409dd35accbf3551e60ecc06617f) and is available in [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) today.

That way, you can switch branch without VSCode closing files without warning.